# Centring a table on a two-column page beyond the text limits

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, multicolumn, multicol

I have an 'oversized' table in a two-column document that I would like to centre in the page. However, I cannot get it to work using `\centering` or `\begin{center}`. I added an example document as well as jlmr2e.sty.

How do I make sure this and other similar tables are centred?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{jmlr2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,
              justification=raggedright,
              singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Definitions of handy macros can go here

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\footnotesize {T Stack | An example document}}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\newcommand{\dataset}{{\cal D}}
\newcommand{\fracpartial}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial  #2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{table*}[]
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.12\textwidth}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{center}
\caption{Patient characteristics.}
\begin{tabular}{lllll|lll}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Temporal} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Model} \\ \hline
 & All & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Discharged \\ (no ICU)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Discharged \\ after ICU\end{tabular} & Deceased & All & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Essential \\ Hosp.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Non-essential \\ Hosp.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Female (\%) & 349 (38.3) & 318 (38.9) & 24 (33.8) & 7 (30.4) & 576 (39.6) & \textbf{501 (38.5)} & \textbf{75 (48.7)} \\
Age & 59.3 (14.0) & \textbf{59.0 (14.2)} & \textbf{60.0 (11.3)} & \textbf{68.6 (8.8)} & 63.7 (15.1) & \textbf{64.3 (14.5)} & \textbf{58.5 (18.4)} \\
Tocilizumab (\%) & 5 (0.6) & 4 (0.5) & 1 (1.5) & 0 (0.0) & 6 (0.4) & 6 (0.5) & 0 (0.0) \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{adjustbox}
\label{pick_LOS}
\end{table*}

Example filler text

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

And jlmr2e.sty:

```
% Change the overall width of the page.  If these parameters are
%       changed, they will require corresponding changes in the
%       maketitle section.
%
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.95}   % let figure take up nearly whole page
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}  % let figure take up nearly whole page

% Specify the dimensions of each page

\oddsidemargin .0in    %   Note \oddsidemargin = \evensidemargin
\evensidemargin .0in
\marginparwidth 0.07 true in
%\marginparwidth 0.75 true in
%\topmargin 0 true pt           % Nominal distance from top of page to top of
%\topmargin 0.125in
\topmargin -0.5in
\addtolength{\headsep}{0.25in}
\textheight 8.5 true in       % Height of text (including footnotes & figures)
\textwidth 6.5 true in        % Width of text line.
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\@twosidetrue \@mparswitchtrue \def\ds@draft{\overfullrule 5pt}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to allow a table to overflow into the margins if you can make sure it fits into the available space. The following MWE shows how you can make sure the table is exactly as wide as the textwidth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{jmlr2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,
              justification=raggedright,
              singlelinecheck=false}

\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{table*}
\begin{threeparttable}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\caption{Patient characteristics.}
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lllll lll}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Temporal} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Model} \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-8}
 & \thead{All} & \thead{Discharged \\ (no ICU)} & \thead{Discharged \\ after ICU} & \thead{Deceased} & \thead{All} & \thead{Essential \\ Hosp.} & \thead{Non-essential \\ Hosp.} \\ \midrule
Female (\%)      & 349 (38.3)  & 318 (38.9)           & 24 (33.8)            & 7 (30.4)            & 576 (39.6)  & \textbf{501 (38.5)}  & \textbf{75 (48.7)}   \\
Age              & 59.3 (14.0) & \textbf{59.0 (14.2)} & \textbf{60.0 (11.3)} & \textbf{68.6 (8.8)} & 63.7 (15.1) & \textbf{64.3 (14.5)} & \textbf{58.5 (18.4)} \\
Tocilizumab (\%) & 5 (0.6)     & 4 (0.5)              & 1 (1.5)              & 0 (0.0)             & 6 (0.4)     & 6 (0.5)              & 0 (0.0)              \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{threeparttable}
\label{pick_LOS}
\end{table*}

Example filler text

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked beautifully!

Answer (score 2):

You need the `adjustwidth` environment from the changepage`package *not* the`adjustbox`environment from the`adjustbox` package.

```
% multicolprob.tex  SE 611887

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{jmlr2e}   %%% see below
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf,
              justification=raggedright,
              singlelinecheck=false}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% jlmr2e.sty

% Change the overall width of the page.  If these parameters are
%       changed, they will require corresponding changes in the
%       maketitle section.
%
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.95}   % let figure take up nearly whole page
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}  % let figure take up nearly whole page

% Specify the dimensions of each page

\oddsidemargin .0in    %   Note \oddsidemargin = \evensidemargin
\evensidemargin .0in
\marginparwidth 0.07 true in
%\marginparwidth 0.75 true in
%\topmargin 0 true pt           % Nominal distance from top of page to top of
%\topmargin 0.125in
\topmargin -0.5in
\addtolength{\headsep}{0.25in}
\textheight 8.5 true in       % Height of text (including footnotes & figures)
\textwidth 6.5 true in        % Width of text line.
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\makeatletter
\@twosidetrue \@mparswitchtrue \def\ds@draft{\overfullrule 5pt}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Definitions of handy macros can go here

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\footnotesize {T Stack | An example document}}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\newcommand{\dataset}{{\cal D}}
\newcommand{\fracpartial}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial  #2}}

\usepackage{changepage}


\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{table*}%[]
%\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.12\textwidth}
%\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.8\textwidth}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\begin{threeparttable}
%\begin{center}
\centering
\caption{Patient characteristics.}
\begin{tabular}{lllll|lll}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Temporal} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Model} \\ \hline
 & All & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Discharged \\ (no ICU)\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Discharged \\ after ICU\end{tabular} & Deceased & All & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Essential \\ Hosp.\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Non-essential \\ Hosp.\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Female (\%) & 349 (38.3) & 318 (38.9) & 24 (33.8) & 7 (30.4) & 576 (39.6) & \textbf{501 (38.5)} & \textbf{75 (48.7)} \\
Age & 59.3 (14.0) & \textbf{59.0 (14.2)} & \textbf{60.0 (11.3)} & \textbf{68.6 (8.8)} & 63.7 (15.1) & \textbf{64.3 (14.5)} & \textbf{58.5 (18.4)} \\
Tocilizumab (\%) & 5 (0.6) & 4 (0.5) & 1 (1.5) & 0 (0.0) & 6 (0.4) & 6 (0.5) & 0 (0.0) \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
%\end{center}
\end{threeparttable}
%\end{adjustbox}
\end{adjustwidth}
\label{pick_LOS}
\end{table*}

Example filler text

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Also, use `\centering` not the `center` environment within floats.

Also, the `jmlr2e` seems to have no bearing on the placement of the table.